# Angular re-attempt API request if HTTP error code is 500

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

I am trying to add a simple HTTP re-attempt to my API calls as

```
this.http.post(url, {payload})
    .pipe(retry(3)).sub.....
```

How do I add the following cases?

1. Only 3 Re-attempts
2. At an interval of 1 sec
3. Only when the HTTP error code is 500

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `retryWhen` from RxJS to retry any requests. below is a code snippet that tries for 3 times before throwing the error:

```
private handleRetry<T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
        return source.pipe(retryWhen(e => e.pipe(scan((errorCount, error) => {
            if (errorCount >= 3) {
                throw error;
            }
            return errorCount + 1;
        }, 0),
            delay(1000)
        )));
    }
```

in the component call you can make use of `handleRetry`  :

```
this.http.post(url, {payload})
    .pipe(this.handleRetry).sub.....
```

You can also `tap` into the error to decide if you have to retry based on the status code:
Ex:

```
server.getData().pipe(
  retryWhen(errors =>
    errors.pipe(
      delay(1000),
      tap(errorStatus => {
        if (!errorStatus.startsWith('5')) {
          throw errorStatus;
        }

        console.log('Retrying...');
      })
    )
  )
);
```